# scale CSS não expande o container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css-hover

Bom dia. Tenho um exercício que estou fazendo no bootcamp que não consigo encontrar a resposta. É pra fazer em bootstrap e colocar as imagens que ao passar o mouse sobre elas a largura e a altura aumentem de maneira suave de 140px para 200px.
Ok, em partes, consegui fazer o transform scale funcionar, mas sempre que ela expande, ela extrapola o tamanho do container não trazendo o conteúdo para baixo.

Como deve ficar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como está ficando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Colo aqui meu código html das imagens:

```css
.wrap img {
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}
.wrap img:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.4285714286);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4285714286);
  -o-transform: scale(1.4285714286);
  transform: scale(1.4285714286);
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<main class="container">
        <div class="row p-3">
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 text-center p-3">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center wrap">
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://hablandodenutricion.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/abdominal.jpg" alt="Treino funcional" class="circular-img">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h3>Treinamento funcional</h3>
                <p>O treinamento funcional baseia-se no movimento natural do ser humano como correr, pular e empurrar.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 text-center p-3">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center wrap">
                    <img src="https://www.workout-italia.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/corso-personal-trainer.jpg" alt="Treino físico" class="circular-img">
                </div>
                <h3>Treino físico</h3>
                <p>Treinamento de cada grupo muscular trabalhando duas vezes na semana usando aparelhos de academia.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 text-center  p-3">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center wrap" >
                    <img src="https://www.meditaya.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/yoga-2959226_1920.jpg" alt="Ioga" class="circular-img">
                </div>
                <h3>Ioga</h3>
                <p>É um conceito que se refere às tradicionais disciplinas físicas e mentais originárias da Índia.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Valeu povo. Tô perdido nisso.

Comment: O scale não afeta os elementos periféricos ou o container. Teria que aumentar o width e o height ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Aplique o hover no DIV "pai" do IMG, então calcule `140 * 1.42` = 198 (aproximado, deve dar "197 quebrado", mas arredonde para 198), então faça: `.wrap > div:hover { height: 198px;  }` e `.wrap > div:hover > img { transform: scale(1.4285714286); }`

Comment: Gente, valeu pelas dicas. Achei uma resposta aqui, já coloco.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A resposta que encontrei foi:

```css
.circular-img {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition-property: width height;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
.circular-img:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<main class="container">
        <div class="row p-3">
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 text-center p-3">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center wrap">
                    <div>
                        <img src="https://hablandodenutricion.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/abdominal.jpg" alt="Treino funcional" class="circular-img">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h3>Treinamento funcional</h3>
                <p>O treinamento funcional baseia-se no movimento natural do ser humano como correr, pular e empurrar.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 text-center p-3">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center wrap">
                    <img src="https://www.workout-italia.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/corso-personal-trainer.jpg" alt="Treino físico" class="circular-img">
                </div>
                <h3>Treino físico</h3>
                <p>Treinamento de cada grupo muscular trabalhando duas vezes na semana usando aparelhos de academia.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 text-center  p-3">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center wrap" >
                    <img src="https://www.meditaya.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/yoga-2959226_1920.jpg" alt="Ioga" class="circular-img">
                </div>
                <h3>Ioga</h3>
                <p>É um conceito que se refere às tradicionais disciplinas físicas e mentais originárias da Índia.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

O scale também funciona para aumentar o elemento, mas não aumenta o container. Então foi como o Sam falou, aumentando o width e o height ao mesmo tempo.